# ruby merge two statements in to one

Tags: ruby

This question is for very very specific case, where I may change params. This is not a part of any rails app.

params is `{:email => "    ab", :xyz => "    ", :opq => nil}`
I run following :

```
params.each{|_, v| v.strip! if v}
params.keep_if{|_, v| v.length > 0 if v}
```

to get params as 
`{:email => "ab"}`

is there anyway to merge above two lines into one?

Comment: I would consider it bad form to mutate the `params` object in rails.  Use a method that returns a new hash instead. Like say `Hash#select`.

Comment: yes, remove the line-feed and insert a dot ;-) `params.each{|_, v| v.strip! if v}.keep_if{|_, v| v.length > 0 if v}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :011 > params ={:email => " ab", :xyz => " ", :opq => nil}
 => {:email=>" ab", :xyz=>" ", :opq=>nil} 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 :012 > params.reject! { |_, v| !v || v.strip!.length == 0 }
 => {:email=>"ab"}
```

Comment: Use `strip!` to match the asker's desired value.

Comment: isn't the complexity in making this elegant that he wants to both select specific elements *and* transform them (strip) in one statement?

Comment: @Dave It does not change params. I have to take help of intermediate variable. `ab = params.select { |_, v| v && v.strip.length > 0 }`  and then `params = ab` so still two lines

Comment: @JVK `params = params.select ..` (so one line still, *without icky sneaky side-effects*)

Comment: @JVK Correct, nor IMO should you. Modified answer to do the wrong thing.

Comment: @JVK Who said anything about Rails? This is output from irb; I do not see an exception.

Comment: @DaveNewton My bad I jumped to give you answer before checking your changes. My bad.

Comment: @DaveNewton I selected your answer. Thanks bro.

Comment: @JVK You should consider unselecting this answer because it is wrong. The answerer does not know how to use destructive methods. When you have an empty string, `strip!` will return `nil`, on which `length` is not defined, and will crash.

Comment: @sawa So answer the question, or edit in the simple fix. Someone making a silly mistake means they "don't know how to use destructive methods"? Is this how you approach things in real life? I'm skeptical you've never made a silly error, say, like believing floating point multiplication isn't subject to the same inaccuracies as addition. Flag away.

Answer (score 1):

```
params.each{|_, v| v.strip! if v}.reject!{|_, v| !v || v.length == 0}
```

Comment: I would avoid the use of side-effect functions unless there is a good need: in this case, I can't argue there is (but can argue here isn't).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the lines you wrote are chainable:

```
params.each{|_, v| v.strip! if v}.keep_if{|_, v| v.length > 0 if v}
```

This works because `each` returns the object itself (which was updated). However, IMHO in-place updates are usually a bad idea, so here's a functional approach:

```
params2 = Hash[params.map { |k, v| [k, v.strip] if v && v.strip.size > 0 }.compact]
```

But this is unnecessarily verbose because the stdlib lacks some fundamental abstractions. With the aid of `Enumerable#mash` and `Object#present?` it's as simple as:

```
params2 = params.mash { |k, v| [k, v.strip] if v.present? }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option that seems to technically answer your question, but I'm guessing it is not what you are looking for:

```
params.select{|_,v| v.strip.length > 0 if v}
```

The fundamental trouble you are running into is that Hash#map does **not** return a Hash but rather an Array.  Many people, including myself, find this annoying.  See for example: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/185611

Here is a verbose option using inject.

```
params.inject({}) {|h,(k,v)| h.merge(k => v ? v.strip : v)}.select{|_,v| v.length > 0 if v}
```

If it matters to you, neither of these solutions will make any destructive changes to params.

```
1.9.3-p125 :030 > params = {:email => " ab", :xyz => " ", :opq => nil}
 => {:email=>" ab", :xyz=>" ", :opq=>nil} 
1.9.3-p125 :031 > params.inject({}) {|h,(k,v)| h.merge(k => v ? v.strip : v)}.select{|_,v|   v.length > 0 if v}
 => {:email=>"ab"} 
1.9.3-p125 :032 > params
 => {:email=>" ab", :xyz=>" ", :opq=>nil}
```

Inject is a tricky function that takes some getting used to.  I'll try to explain this line step by step:

- `params.inject({}}` says to create an empty hash to store our results in.
- |h, (k,v)| says to pass the new empty hash into the variable h while also passing the key, value pair from our original params hash into k, v respectively.

Next it get's kindof hairy.  I'll unpack the next command from the inside out.

- `v ? v.strip : v` uses the ternary operator to return v.strip in the case that v evaluates to true or v in the case that v is false or nil
- `k => v ? v.strip : v` creates a new hash with the result
- `h.merge(k => v ? v.strip : v)` merges our new hash into h, which started out empty, and then passes the result onto the next iteration of the inject loop.
- in the next iteration of the loop, h will no longer be empty and future results will continue to be merged onto it.

At this point we have stripped the hash and if we stopped here the result looks like this:

```
1.9.3-p125 :032 > params
 => {:email=>" ab", :xyz=>" ", :opq=>nil} 
1.9.3-p125 :033 > params.inject({}) {|h,(k,v)| h.merge(k => v ? v.strip : v)}
 => {:email=>"ab", :xyz=>"", :opq=>nil}
```

Now that the hash is stripped, the select statement is straight forward.  I use select here rather than keep_if, because, despite the lack of a !, keep_if is a destructive method.  See this rant: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2247352. Since our inject statement returns a hash we can directly call `.select` on it, although I don't suggest making your lines of code this long in actual practice.

```
1.9.3-p125 :034 > params
 => {:email=>" ab", :xyz=>" ", :opq=>nil} 
1.9.3-p125 :035 > params.inject({}) {|h,(k,v)| h.merge(k => v ? v.strip : v)}.select{|_,v| v.length > 0 if v}
 => {:email=>"ab"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
params.keys.each{|k| v = h.delete(k); h[k] = v.strip if v and !v.empty?}
```

or

```
params.select!{|k, v| v and v.strip!; v and !v.empty?}
```